# How can I detect an archive, that is encrypted?

Tags: c++, c, archive

I can detect a archive type using libmagic or file command. But if that archive type is encrypted, i cant detect that archive is encrypted. Also I want to differentiate archive and encrypted archive. How can i do that? Do you know any tools or method to handle it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The goal of good encryption is to hide all encrypted information. Therefore, a well-encrypted archive (as opposed to an archive with encrypted contents) is _by definition_ not recognizable as an archive.

Comment: 7zip is well-known archive type and have good support for encryption. But you can detect that even if encrypted, it is an archive.

Comment: That's an example of an "archive with encrypted contents". But if I take an un-encrypted 7zip archive and encrypt it with PGP, the result will be an encrypted archive. You won't be able to tell anything about the content of the resulting PGP file, so you can't tell that it contains an archive either.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the archive format. Some archives are *completely* encrypted (even the header), so you can't tell they are an archive just by looking at the data, since it's *apparently* random.

For archives that aren't totally encrypted, just looking at the header can give you a hint on what format it is. (See the specifications of the archive formats you are trying to detect).

You could also base yourself on file extension although that is slightly weaker.

Comment: as much as possible i want to detect archive types. Is there any header for information that arcihve is encrypted or not ? and ecrypted or plain archive has same output by file command for example :  7-zip archive data, version 0.3

Comment: There is no general way, as I said. To detect archives you have to read the file header and check for the presence of an archive header. (`37 7A` in the case of 7z). This only works if the header itself is not encrypted.